visual studio keep ask repeatedly to install command line tools
in visual studio, whenever i want to run my python code, the terminal always say :dangtruongan@Ans-Macbook-Air ~ % python -u "/var/folders/xb/q6y456rd0wb3y1h6ht5qpth00000gn/T/tempCodeRunnerFile.python"
xcode-select: Failed to locate 'python', requesting installation of command line developer tools.
and then this 
will pop up. And although i have installed this mutiple times, it still ask me to install again and again.
Then only way for me now to run python is to use normal python3 + file folder in command line.
yes this only pop up when i click the run button in the top right of visual studio
i think this happen because i accidently delete python launcher and idle yesterday, but i installed it back.

The CLT does not install a python, so I would not expect that to work.  It does install a python3.  I'd think you were getting the prompt to install the CLT because CodeRunner is launching xcode-select.  Look at your CodeRunner config.

Visual Studio only runs on Windows unless you have a 2022 beta. There is another produce which is different that is Visual Studio Code,
